# How to validate postal code by country id?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, country-regions

In Magento checkout there is a postal code verification for each country, now I want to implement it in different module for different case, how to do it if I already have the country id and postal code as the parameter, for example:

```
$postalCode = '15433';
$countryId = 'UK';
$this->validatePostalCode($countryId,$postalCode);

public function validatePostalCode($countryId,$postalCode){
  // how?
  if($valid) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
public function validatePostalCode($countryId,$postalCode){
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $postCodeValidator = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Directory\Model\Country\Postcode\ValidatorInterface::class);
  return (bool) $postCodeValidator->validate($postalCode,$countryId);
}
```

Comment: Direct use of object manager is not recommended, kindly use constructor dependency injection instead.

Answer (score 0):

Extend class or add a plugin :
namespace Magento\Directory\Model\Country\Postcode;

class Validator implements ValidatorInterface
{

and overwrite function :
public function validate($postcode, $countryId){}

This is the function to be debugged and modified